# Can a call to Task.GetAwaiter().OnCompleted() fail because of garbage collection?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, task-parallel-library

Example:

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
  Thread.Sleep(1000);
  throw new Exception("fault!");
});

task.GetAwaiter().OnCompleted(() =>
{
  if (task.IsFaulted)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(task.Exception);
  }
});
```

The code above waits for task completion using a **TaskAwaiter**. I've seen code like this in several examples throughout the web, either with **OnCompleted** or with **GetResult**.

Is it necessary to keep a reference to the awaiter explicitly in order for the callback to work? In other words, is it a problem if the awaiter is garbage collected before the task terminates?

Comment: `I've seen code like this in several examples throughout the web, either with OnCompleted or with GetResult.` Wow, I sure hope not; this is a *horrible* pattern! As Peter points out, `await` is far superior - or even `ContinueWith`, if you must. Oh, and `Task.Run` > `StartNew`, and `Task.Exception` will give you an `AggregateException` instead of the one you want. Yeah, pretty much everything about this code snippet is suboptimal.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I ended up refactoring my design and it was much cleaner using async/await everywhere. I had to keep using StartNew though, only because it seems to be the only way to specify `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` and I do need it.

Comment: As I explain on my blog, [you probably don't *really* need `LongRunning`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html) - the thread pool adjusts in 500ms if you *don't* pass it. If you do decide to keep `StartNew`, **be sure to explicitly specify a scheduler** as well as the `DenyChildAttach` flag.

Comment: I've read your blog article actually, it was nice. However, while it is true the thread pool adjusts its **size** in 500 ms, the Task itself is not promoted to a Thread. My long running task is really just a Thread that will be active throughout the whole of the application's lifetime, so there's really no question that LongRunning makes the most sense. I really don't want these permanent tasks messing around with thread injection thresholds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, after appreciation of all the answers and comments, my realization about using `GetAwaiter()` is: **don't do it**.

If you need it, this is most likely an indication that your asynchronous design is in badly need of refactoring.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it necessary to keep a reference to the awaiter explicitly in order for the callback to work? In other words, is it a problem if the awaiter is garbage collected before the task terminates?

I don't see how it could be. The only way it could be a problem is if something needed to use the awaiter object. But for it to try to do so, it would have to have a reference to the awaiter object. But if it has a reference to the awaiter object, the object wouldn't be garbage collected.

That said, why are you implementing a continuation in this way? Typically, you'd just use `await` and write the continuation in the same method after the `await` call. Even in scenarios where that doesn't work for some reason (e.g. not in an `async` method), you would normally use the `ContinueWith()` method.

Why are you calling `GetAwaiter()`? It sounds like you might benefit from providing a bit more detail in your question, so that an answer that addresses your broader need could be provided (or you could just ask a second question to solicit advice on that).